# How to optimize R script involving dyplr package (Example given )?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a huge data file called df (8 GB) and I want to do some data manipulation using dyplr as explained below .

```
df<-data.frame(customer=c("x","x","x","y","y"),location_id=c(100,100,100,200,200),
           report_date=c("2019-12-12","2019-12-12","2019-12-12","2019-11-12","2019-11-12"),
           local_hour=c(10,11,11,4,5),created_time=c("2019-12-22 15:50:04","2019-12-22 
16:50:04","2019-12-22 17:55:07","2019-11-22 05:50:04","2019-11-22 06:53:04"))


df$created_time<- as.POSIXct(df$created_time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This is the data manipulation step that I am focussing on and temp1 takes 25 minutes to execute

```
temp1 <-df %>% 
group_by(customer,location_id,report_date,local_hour)%>%
summarise(created_time = max(created_time)) %>%
ungroup()
```

This is my expected data frame and this step takes 3-4 minutes to execute

```
expected_df<-df%>% 
inner_join(temp1) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

Basically this is my data set

```
df
customer location_id report_date local_hour        created_time
x         100  2019-12-12         10    2019-12-22 15:50:04
x         100  2019-12-12         11    2019-12-22 16:50:04
x         100  2019-12-12         11    2019-12-22 17:55:07
y         200  2019-11-12          4    2019-11-22 05:50:04
y         200  2019-11-12          5    2019-11-22 06:53:04
```

This is what I get and that is my objective as well , but problem is , it is taking 30+ minutes to execute and affecting my scheduled task . Do you guys have any better way to execute it faster ?

```
expected_df
customer location_id report_date local_hour        created_time
x         100  2019-12-12         10     2019-12-22 15:50:04
x         100  2019-12-12         11     2019-12-22 17:55:07
y         200  2019-11-12          4     2019-11-22 05:50:04
y         200  2019-11-12          5     2019-11-22 06:53:04
```

Comment: Here is a variation in `dplyr`, `df %>% 
  group_by(customer,location_id,report_date,local_hour)%>%
  slice(which.max(created_time))` Or you can try `data.table` for higher speed gain `setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(created_time)], .(customer,location_id,report_date,local_hour)]`

Comment: look into data.table instead as it is faster given you can do parallel processing and runs data cleaning at a fraction of the speed that dplyr does

Comment: Definitely a job for `data.table`. Parallel processing, in-place modifications, fast indexing. It is possible to mix tidyverse stuff with data.table using `dtplyr` instead of `dplyr`, but it requires special care to avoid slow syntax, as other aspects of the tidyverse (tidyr, pipes) don't take advantage of data.table's performance.